# How to delete ALL duplicate records (including the original)

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008 tsql, I'm trying to remove ALL the records in a table when a set of values recur.  So if my table looked like this:

<kbd>id</kbd><kbd>col1</kbd><kbd>col2</kbd>
 <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd>    <kbd>1</kbd>  
 <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd>    <kbd>1</kbd>  
 <kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd>    <kbd>2</kbd>  
 <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>    <kbd>1</kbd>  
 <kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>    <kbd>1</kbd>  
 <kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>B</kbd>    <kbd>2</kbd>

Rows 1, 2, 4, 5 would all be deleted.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan: Not for nothing, but I tried a ton of crap. None of which worked, so I don't see how adding it here would help. I've also read numerous articles on this site, but I keep running into solutions that involve leaving one of the duplicates. Thanks for that though, I feel real welcome asking my first question on this site now.

Comment: Gotta give this to Sebastian Meine cause his answer worked right out of the box.  I struggled for a while trying to get Aaron Bertrand's solution to work as I was getting syntax errors in SQL 2008 until his final edit.  Learned lots from both answers though, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE t
FROM dbo.yourTabe t
JOIN (
  SELECT col1,col2,COUNT(1) cnt
  FROM dbo.YourTable
  GROUP BY col1, col2
  HAVING COUNT(1)>1
) s
ON t.col1 = s.col1
AND t.col2 = s.col2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, c = COUNT(*) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1)
  FROM dbo.yourtable
)
DELETE d WHERE c > 1;
```

In fact it can be *slightly* tidier:

```
;WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT id, c = COUNT(*) OVER 
    (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col1)
  FROM dbo.yourtable
)
DELETE d WHERE c > 1;
```

And I'll fess up, I tested the above on SQL Server 2012, however I forgot to change the fiddle to SQL Server 2008. For versions prior to SQL Server 2012, here is one variation:

```
;WITH d AS 
(
  SELECT col1, col2
  FROM dbo.yourtable AS t
  GROUP BY col1, col2
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
DELETE t --*
FROM dbo.yourtable AS t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM d 
  WHERE col1 = t.col1 AND col2 = t.col2
);
```

- You'd think it would be sufficient to just `DELETE d;` here but you get:

> Msg 4403, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Cannot update the view or function 'd' because it contains aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT operator.